# How does user tagging in comments really work?

Tags: discussion, comments

When you comment directly to people, the usual routine is to '@user yes, but, but'.  With users of certain lower[new, or uninvolved] reps, or lower age, it simply doesn't work.  Try to comment on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35396/what-happens-with-krypto-when-superman-becomes-an-adult) question, or others similarly new (obviously within a couple of days of this question, for that sample.)

I'm not asking for a change, but a reason why.  We have issues with asks-and-runs, so I'm not sure this is a good thing.  *@dude[tte] Please checkmark my answer to your shenanigans if you dig it.*

If it's just me and my browser [very specifically problematic], flame away at Chrome.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "with players of certain lower[new, or uninvolved] reps, or lower age, it simply doesn't work".  Reputation/age of the account have no bearing on the notification system.  Asks-and-runs won't be fixed by comment notifications, anyway.  You only see the notification if you log back in to the site. If someone asks, and never comes back, they'll never see a notification regardless of whether the system works or not.

Comment: Don't nag askers to accept your answer. It's rude and pointless (either they're gone for good and won't see your message, or they're still here and will accept when they feel like it).

Comment: @Gilles A single polite reminder isn't nagging by definition; and the incident that it came up with me leading to this question was a comment asking for more detail. I just used that example as a possible motivator. [edited for less durrrness]

Comment: Understand the question- how does it work, stop examining my motivation; this question is pretty clear, and this isn't a pub.  How does it work?  Question says 'how... work'  not 'why... shit doesn't get answered'.  Be adults.  I went further to be broad, be broad in your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment tagging is limited to other commenters who have commented *in that thread*, who aren't the poster of the question/answer. If the OP comments on your post you can `@tag` them, but if you post on their question/answer you don't have to. They're automatically notified.

Comment: To be more specific, when you try to tag a person when commenting on that person's post, SE software will **remove** your tag.

Comment: @DVK I think that's only if that person has not yet commented on their own post.  Once they have, you can @ them.  It's good for indicating "I am responding to the original post" vs "I am responding to your comment"

Comment: @Izkata - good catch! +1

Comment: @DVK Scratch that, it apparently requires both the OP _and_ someone besides yourself to have commented for it to work on the OP...?  Weird.  'Tho I guess being the only 2 in the convo, it kinda makes sense

Comment: @Izkata - Never ascribe to an elegant well thought out design what can be easily explained by a random bug :)